# Is every polynomial a limit of polynomials in quadratic variables?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $d>0$ be even. Consider ${\mathbb{R}}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]_d$, i.e. polynomials of degree $d$.

Call a homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ a *polynomial in quadratic variables* if it is of the form $f=p(y_1^2,\ldots, y_n^2)$ for some polynomial $p$. Here the $y_i=y_i(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ are linear forms such that $\{y_1,\ldots, y_n\}$ is a basis of the degree 1 polynomials ${\mathbb{R}}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_1$.

For example if we take $p(x,y)=5x^3y^4+(x-3y)^3$, and $x-y, x+y$ to be the linear polynomials, then this gives the example of $5(x-y)^6(x+y)^8+((x-y)^2-3(x+y)^2)^3$ $=5(x-y)^6(x+y)^8-(2x^2+8xy+2y^2)^3$ as an example of a polynomial in quadratic variables.

Is it true that polynomials in quadratic variables are dense in the vector space ${\mathbb{R}}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]_d$? In other words, it every polynomial of degree $d$ a limit of polynomials of degree $d$ in quadratic variables?

**Edit:** In response to Pete, Ewan's and Darij's comments, I will rephrase this question in terms of ring automorphisms. Firstly, let's ignore odd degree polynomials. In the language of linear change of variables, let $V$ be a real vector space space of dimension $n$. Consider the ring $\mathbb{R}[x_1^2,\ldots, x_n^2]$. Each choice of basis $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ of the vector space $V$ induces a ring monomorphism $\mathcal{B}_*:\mathbb{R}[x_1^2,\ldots, x_n^2]\to Sym(V)$ to the symmetric algebra on $V$. This monomorphism is given by extending the map $x_i^2\mapsto v_i$.

Is every even degree element of $Sym(V)$ in the image of some induced monomorphism $\mathcal{B}_*$?

Comment: I don't get it. The $y_i$ stay fixed? Do you really mean $p(y_1,...,y_n)$ and not $p(y_1^2,...,y_n^2)$ ? What about linear poylnomials?=

Comment: Something is wrong in your question, but I am not sure enough to edit it myself. It seems that $p$ should be $x^3y^4+(x-3y)^3$ and the quadratic forms be $(x-y)^2$ **and** $(x+y)^2$. Thus then they are not positive definite.

Comment: yup. I need some serious editing

Comment: OK, but I still don't see how any non-even polynomial could be a limit of polynomials in quadratic variables.

Comment: Besides, I think you can WLOG set $y_1=x_1$, ..., $y_n=x_n$, because the polynomial ring $\mathbb R\left[x_1,...,x_n\right]$ is just one of many ways to coordinatize the symmetric algebra $\mathrm{Sym} V$ of an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space $V$, and the algebra doesn't change if you pass to different coordinates.

Comment: Darij, How does one write $(x+y)^2-y^2=x^2+2xy$ has a polynomial in the variables $x^2$ and $y^2$?

Comment: @Colin: you can't.  $x^2+2xy$ is not invariant under $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$, whereas any function of $x^2$ and $y^2$ is invariant under this automorphism.  But what's your point?  Darij is saying that you are only going to get polynomials which are even functions *of your variables* $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, so the answer to your question is "no".  (He's also saying that the general case can be reduced to the special case $(y_1,\ldots,y_n) = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ via an automorphism of the ring, but why don't you address his first point first.) 

Comment: @ Darij and Pete : I think Colin meant "for some polynomial p AND some basis of linear forms y1,y2, ... ,yn". This answers Darij's point.

Comment: Yes, thank you ewan. I write an edit in an attempt to clarify Darij and Pete's comments. 

Comment: As the edits go on, your question and your example seem to diverge more and more: your example is not of even degree and not homogeneous.

Comment: @Thierry: I think it makes sense now. He is asking whether polynomials in squared linear variables are dense in even degree homogenous polynomials. His computation is just one example of what one could get if one computes the polynomial $p$ in squared linear variables $x-y$ and $x+y$.

Answer (score 7):

The dimension of the linear space of homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ is 
$\binom{n+d-1}{d}$. The dimension of the space of homogenous polynomials of degree $d$ in squared linear variables is
$$\binom{n+d/2-1}{d/2} \cdot (n^2-1),$$
where $n^2-1 = \dim GL_n(\mathbb R)$. One easily see that if $d$ and $n$ are sufficiently large, then the dimension of the set of squared polynomials is too small to exhaust all homogenous polynomials of degree $d$. Indeed,

$$\binom{n+d/2-1}{d/2} \cdot (n^2-1) \leq \frac{(n-1)\cdot n \cdots (n+d/2-1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots d/2} \cdot n^2$$
$$< \frac{(n-1)\cdot n \cdots (n+d-1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots d} = \binom{n+d-1}{d}$$
if

$$n^2 < \frac{(n+d/2)\cdots (n+d-1)}{(d/2+1) \cdots d} = \prod_{k=1}^{d/2} \frac{n-1+d/2+k}{d/2+k}.$$

But the RHS equals
$$\prod_{k=1}^{d/2} \left( 1+\frac{n-1}{d/2+k} \right) \geq \left( 1+\frac{n-1}{d} \right)^{d/2} \sim \exp\left(\frac{n-1}2 \right)$$
for large $d$. So, if $n$ is large, we get $n^2 < \exp\left(\frac{n-1}2 \right) \leq \frac{(n+d/2)\cdots (n+d-1)}{(d/2+1) \cdots d}$ and this implies the claim.